# How to update Entity but insert new row on SaveChanges?

Tags: entity-framework

I have Entity1 with properties

```
Entity1.id= 1;
Entity1.a = 10;
Entity1.b = 123;
Entity1.c = 231;
```

I wan't to change properties but to insert a new row on context.SaveChanges() not to do update for existing id.
I tried to set `Entity1.entityKey = null` but it fails.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want a kind of 'copy an entity'?

Comment: Kind of, yes, but to change some properties too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `EntityState` to `Added` in the `ObjectStateManager`:

```
var Entity1 = context.YourEntities.Where(e => e.Id == 1).FirstOrDefault();

ObjectStateEntry osmEntry = context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(Entity1);
osmEntry.ChangeState(EntityState.Added);

context.SaveChanges();
```

That is if your entity is already attached to the context (e.g. if you fetched it before).

This will 'copy' the entity with `Id = 1` unless you make any changes to the properties.